# Transition Animations between Activities wont be displayed

Tags: android, animation

I'm using this to override the transiting animation between two activities. At first it worked properly but now, the animation won't be displayed, though it was a problem with current project so I started a new one and the same thing happens. Is this a thing caused by my device? it is a samsung galaxy S advance with 2.3.6 android. Thank you in advance

this is the code on the activity that is started:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);


}
```

and this is the first Activty that calls the second, I've just put the override immediately after startActivity and it won't work either.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: :/ tottaly forgot that sorry..

Comment: where is startActivity code? overridePendingTransition should be after startActivity code

Comment: you have to call that method after your startActivity method.

Comment: android.R.anim.slide_in_left empty?????? or same both xml files?????

Comment: change this Intent intent = new Intent(classname.this,Activity2.class);

Comment: @Monica he gave a space in the override pending transition that should actually cause the compiler to fail actually.

Comment: @Yogamurthy if the space is the problem..then eclipse will show the error..

Comment: use this example http://androidiosappdevelopment.blogspot.in/2012/07/simplest-way-to-change-default.html

Comment: This was just in the process of tinkering with the code...I've edited it, still won't work

Comment: @Monica intent context is the not the problem.if the context is problem activity won't start.I think animations are disabled for that phone..

Comment: @Monice I've changed it to what you suggested and nothing happened :/

Comment: @libathos did u changed intent? just try once

Comment: @kalyanpvs even i said the same .

Comment: @Monica I did, and have the overide just below startActivity()

Comment: @Yogamurthy ok..but he is saying Activity is started.so code is compiled..may be that is copy paste mistake..

Comment: @libathos i m saying to  change like this :::: Intent intent = new Intent(classname.this,Activity2.class)

Comment: @libathos did you enable all animations in settings?

Comment: @Yogamurthy setting means?

Comment: @Yogamurthy where do you mean?

Comment: @libathos i mean Android settings

Comment: @Monica yeah I've done it as you said, I've just edited my post.

Comment: @libathos post ur anim xml plz

Comment: @Monica those are predefined in android, it's not custom....

Comment: @libathos okay, upload ur code somewhere and share the link

Comment: @libathos do this once  Settings->Display->Animations and select "All Animations".

Comment: @Monica Nice! thanks so much :) I was pretty sure it was something about my device

Comment: @Monica post an official answer

Comment: Settings->Developer Options->window ANimation Scale->Animation scale 1x select that one..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> HI , Make sure following step is true for your device :

**Settings**->**Display**->**Animations** and **select "All Animations"**

Answer (score 1):

[overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29):

> Call immediately after one of the flavors of `startActivity(Intent)` or `finish()` to specify an explicit transition animation to perform next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your overridepending() code after starting a new intent. Also enable all animations in settings otherwise those animations wont be displayed.

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim. slide_in_left);
```

change the above to

```
overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left,android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
```

why do you keep both animations as one.try different xml

Comment: I've tried different and removed the space..didn't even see it thanks for pointing it out but that wasn't it